# Handling complex array with MATLAB mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, complex-numbers

I am calling mex from MATLAB, and trying to do arithmetic calculation with complex array using for loop. The complex array is a 4-D matrix dynamically created by

```
g->cjxyp = new complex<double>[len_cjxyp];
```

4-D index is realized by marcro

```
#define cjxypG(g,MM,NN,PP,QQ)       g->cjxyp[(QQ-1)*cjxypM*cjxypN*cjxypP+(PP-1)*cjxypM*cjxypN+(NN-1)*cjxypM+(MM-1)]
#define cjxyp(MM,NN,PP,QQ)             cjxypG(g,MM,NN,PP,QQ)
```

When I printed an element from this array using

```
cout<<cjxyp(1,46,1,18).real()<<'\n';
```

Everything seemed to be OK but when I put it into a for loop

```
    for (mi=1;mi<number_of_farfield_frequencies+1;mi++)
{
    exp_h = dt*exp(-j*farfield_w(mi)*(time_step-0.5)*dt);
    for(ii=1;ii<cjxypN+1;ii++)
    {
        for(jj=1;jj<cjxypP+1;jj++)
        {
            for(kk=1;kk<cjxypQ+1;kk++)
            {
                cout<<mi<<','<<ii<<','<<jj<<','<<kk<<'\n';
                cout<<cjxyp(mi,ii,jj,kk).real()<<'\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The cout lines causes MATLAB to crash. Where is the bug?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. As it stands, we cannot know where the bug is because there are too many unknowns. You are likely reading out of bounds, but we'd need to know what the bounds are.

Comment: How is len_cjxyp calculated? Is it number_of_farfield_frequencies x cjxypN x cjxypP x cjxypQ? What is farfield_w?

Comment: I see. Next time I will post a smaller question for learning purpose. Those code segments are from some hundreds of lines of code.